# Goto Next After Clicking Next From Drop-down Option Using PHP

Tags: php

I want to make a GPA calculator PHP webpage. I choose three pages for this job. In 1st page, Select Semester from drop-down option and click next and goto selected semester. I coded only for the 1st to go to next but failed. I'm a beginner in PHP. The codes are given below:

```
 <form action="PHP/semester.php" method = "POST">
      Select Semester :
      <select name = "semesterwise">
       <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1st Semester</option>
        <option value="2">2nd Semester</option>
        <option value="3">3rd Semester</option>
        <option value="4">4th Semester</option>
        <option value="5">5th Semester</option>
        <option value="6">6th Semester</option>
        <option value="7">7th Semester</option>
        <option value="8">8th Semester</option>
  </select>
<input type="submit" value="Next">
</form>`

php code
      <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['semesterwise']))
    {
        if(strcmp($_POST['semesterwise'],"1") == 0)
        {
            header("Location: 1st.php");
        }
        elseif(strcmp($_POST['semesterwise'],"2" == 0))
        {
            header("Location: 2nd.php");
        }
        -------------------------------------

    ?>
```

Comment: When you do make it to the next page, how are you getting the data for each semester.  Your doing this the hard way coding a php for each semester.  You should be able to do any semester from a single php page.

Comment: In your PHP code, you have written $_POST['submit'] where submit should be the name of a input tag. But your button doesn't has any name. You must use the name of the button in $_POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an quick example of how this should probably be done.

Page 1:

```
<form action="" method = "POST">
      Select Semester :
      <select name = "semesterwise">
       <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1st Semester</option>
        <option value="2">2nd Semester</option>
        <option value="3">3rd Semester</option>
        <option value="4">4th Semester</option>
        <option value="5">5th Semester</option>
        <option value="6">6th Semester</option>
        <option value="7">7th Semester</option>
        <option value="8">8th Semester</option>
  </select>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Next">
</form>

<?php

  if(isset($_POST)) {

    if(isset($_POST['semesterwise']) && $_POST['semesterwise']){
      //Set the id variable to the semester in the url.
      header('Location: semesterPage.php?id=' . $_POST['semesterwise']);
      exit();    

    }

  }

?>
```

semesterPage.php will look something like this:

```
<?php

//Get the id variable from the url.
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']){

  $id = $_GET['id'];
  echo $id . ' is your semester that you selected on page 1.';

  //Do an sql query to get the semester info and display it here.

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML page index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="semester.php" method ="POST">
      Select Semester :
      <select name ="semesterwise">
       <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="1">1st Semester</option>
        <option value="2">2nd Semester</option>
        <option value="3">3rd Semester</option>
        <option value="4">4th Semester</option>
        <option value="5">5th Semester</option>
        <option value="6">6th Semester</option>
        <option value="7">7th Semester</option>
        <option value="8">8th Semester</option>
  </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and create a PHP file as semester.php in the same directory and the file contains following code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if(isset($_POST['semesterwise']))
        {
            switch($_POST['semesterwise']){
                case 1:
                    header("Location: 1st.php");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    header("Location: 2st.php");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

I just created for two pages just make this 8 or more as you want